# Maximum Likelihood parameter estimation for complex polynomial (right skew function) in R

Tags: r, model-fitting, log-likelihood

I have a dataset with y.size and x.number. I am trying to compare the AIC value for a linear regression estimation of the model and a custom model. I was able to successfully run the estimates for the linear regression. The custom model estimation produces this error "Error in optim(start, f, method = method, hessian = TRUE, ...) : non-finite finite-difference value [2]" I am a newbie to ML models, so any help would be appreciated.

```
y.size <- c(2.69,4.1,8.04,3.1,5.27,5.033333333,3.2,7.25,6.29,4.55,6.1,2.65,3.145,3.775,3.46,5.73,5.31,4.425,3.725,4.32,5,3.09,5.25,5.65,3.48,6.1,10,9.666666667,6.06,5.9,2.665,4.32,3.816666667,3.69,5.8,5,3.72,3.045,4.485,3.642857143,5.5,6.333333333,4.75,6,7.466666667,5.03,5.23,4.85,5.59,5.96,5.33,4.92,4.255555556,6.346666667,4.13,6.33,4,7.35,6.35,4.63,5.13,7.4,4.28,4.233333333,4.3125,6.18,4.3,4.47,4.88,4.5,2.96,2.1,3.7,3.62,5.42,3.8,5.5,3.27,3.36,3.266666667,2.265,3.1,2.51,2.51,4.4,2.64,4.38,4.53,2.29,2.87,3.395,3.26,2.77,3.22,4.31,4.73,4.05,3.48,4.8,4.7,3.05,4.21,5.95,4.39,4.55,4.27,4.955,4.65,3.32,3.48,3.828571429,4.69,4.68,3.76,3.91,4,4.41,4.19,4.733333333,4.32,2.83,3.41,4.42,3.47,3.84,4.39)

x.number <- c(69,62,8,80,13,12,2,22,19,49,840,44,31,56,33,58,91,8,15,86,11,69,12,24,32,27,1,4,26,4,28,33,1516,41,20,58,44,29,58,14,3,3,6,3,26,52,26,29,92,30,18,11,27,19,38,78,57,52,17,45,56,7,37,7,14,13,164,76,82,14,273,122,662,434,126,374,1017,522,374,602,164,5,191,243,134,70,23,130,306,516,414,236,172,164,92,53,50,17,22,27,92,48,30,55,28,296,35,12,350,17,22,53,97,62,92,272,242,170,37,220,452,270,392,314,150,232)

require(bbmle)

linreg <- function(a, b, sigma){
  y.pred <- a + b * x.number
  -sum(dnorm(y.size, mean = y.pred, sd = sigma, log=TRUE ))
}

mle2.linreg.model <- mle(linreg, start = list(a = 5, b = -0.01 , sigma = 1))

summary(mle2.linreg.model)
-logLik(mle2.linreg.model)
AIC(mle2.linreg.model)

skewfun <- function(aa,bb, Tmin, Tmax, sigma){
   y.pred <- aa * x.number * (x.number - Tmin) * ((Tmax - x.number )^(1/bb)) + 2
   -sum(dnorm(y.size, mean = y.pred, sd = sigma, log=TRUE ))
   }

mle2.skewfun.model <- mle(skewfun, start = list(aa = 4/10^27, bb = 1/10 , Tmin = 2 , Tmax = 300, sigma = 0.1))
```

EDIT: After trying the initial answer provided by Simon Woodward, I tried the right skew function with new parameter estimates but I got a similar Error: `Error in solve.default(oout$hessian) : Lapack routine dgesv: system is exactly singular: U[2,2] = 0`. I custom fit the function to get an idea on how the curve should look for this dummy data. I used these parameters to run the ML when I ran into the error. Here is how the raw data + curve looks like. Below is the code used to generate it

[image]

```
y.size <- c(2.69,4.1,8.04,3.1,5.27,5.033333333,3.2,7.25,6.29,4.55,6.1,2.65,3.145,3.775,3.46,5.73,5.31,4.425,3.725,4.32,5,3.09,5.25,5.65,3.48,6.1,10,9.666666667,6.06,5.9,2.665,4.32,3.816666667,3.69,5.8,5,3.72,3.045,4.485,3.642857143,5.5,6.333333333,4.75,6,7.466666667,5.03,5.23,4.85,5.59,5.96,5.33,4.92,4.255555556,6.346666667,4.13,6.33,4,7.35,6.35,4.63,5.13,7.4,4.28,4.233333333,4.3125,6.18,4.3,4.47,4.88,4.5,2.96,2.1,3.7,3.62,5.42,3.8,5.5,3.27,3.36,3.266666667,2.265,3.1,2.51,2.51,4.4,2.64,4.38,4.53,2.29,2.87,3.395,3.26,2.77,3.22,4.31,4.73,4.05,3.48,4.8,4.7,3.05,4.21,5.95,4.39,4.55,4.27,4.955,4.65,3.32,3.48,3.828571429,4.69,4.68,3.76,3.91,4,4.41,4.19,4.733333333,4.32,2.83,3.41,4.42,3.47,3.84,4.39)

x.number <- c(69,62,8,80,13,12,2,22,19,49,840,44,31,56,33,58,91,8,15,86,11,69,12,24,32,27,1,4,26,4,28,33,1516,41,20,58,44,29,58,14,3,3,6,3,26,52,26,29,92,30,18,11,27,19,38,78,57,52,17,45,56,7,37,7,14,13,164,76,82,14,273,122,662,434,126,374,1017,522,374,602,164,5,191,243,134,70,23,130,306,516,414,236,172,164,92,53,50,17,22,27,92,48,30,55,28,296,35,12,350,17,22,53,97,62,92,272,242,170,37,220,452,270,392,314,150,232)
df <- data.frame(x.number, y.size)
df <- df[df$x.number < 750,]

aa <- 1.25/10^88 
bb <- 1/30 
Tdata <- df$x.number
Tmin <- 1
Tmax <- 750


y.pred <- (aa * df$x.number * (df$x.number - Tmin) * abs(Tmax - df$x.number) ^ (1/bb)) + 3
raw.data <- df$y.size

min = Tdata - Tmin
max = Tmax - Tdata

df1 <- data.frame(df$x.number, min, max, y.pred, raw.data)
library(tidyr)
df.long <- gather(df1, data.type, data.measurement, y.pred:raw.data)

#ggplot(aes(x = Tdata , y = raw.data), data = df1) + geom_point()
ggplot(aes(x = Tdata , y = y.pred), data = df1) + geom_point()

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(aes(x = df.x.number , y = data.measurement, color = data.type), data = df.long) + geom_point()
```

Comment: You need to make sure skewfun always gives an answer. You need to prevent or catch the case where bb<=0 because this will give an error in the calculation of y.pred..

Comment: You also need to catch and handle the case where Tmax - x.number could be negative.

Comment: How do I bound the parameters? For e.g. how to bound bb to always be above 0? Similarly for min and max

Comment: I don't think mle provides this functionality. So you will need to use a different package or enforce it inside your skewfun. Ideally you should do it in such a way so that the log likelihood is continuous and differentiable on the parameters (I think this hessian error is due to non-differentiability).

Comment: Try this:  y.pred <- aa * x.number * pmax(0, x.number - Tmin) * pmax(0, Tmax - x.number) ^ (1/bb) + 2

Comment: You might also want to add a parameter for the horizontal baseline, which is currently hardcoded.

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from numerical errors in skewfun, because x.number can be bigger than Tmax. You need to make the skewfun more robust to possible parameter values.

With messy data like this, complex functions tend not to converge to nice solutions. I would prefer a Bayesian approach in this case.

```r
y.size <- c(2.69,4.1,8.04,3.1,5.27,5.033333333,3.2,7.25,6.29,4.55,6.1,2.65,3.145,3.775,3.46,5.73,5.31,4.425,3.725,4.32,5,3.09,5.25,5.65,3.48,6.1,10,9.666666667,6.06,5.9,2.665,4.32,3.816666667,3.69,5.8,5,3.72,3.045,4.485,3.642857143,5.5,6.333333333,4.75,6,7.466666667,5.03,5.23,4.85,5.59,5.96,5.33,4.92,4.255555556,6.346666667,4.13,6.33,4,7.35,6.35,4.63,5.13,7.4,4.28,4.233333333,4.3125,6.18,4.3,4.47,4.88,4.5,2.96,2.1,3.7,3.62,5.42,3.8,5.5,3.27,3.36,3.266666667,2.265,3.1,2.51,2.51,4.4,2.64,4.38,4.53,2.29,2.87,3.395,3.26,2.77,3.22,4.31,4.73,4.05,3.48,4.8,4.7,3.05,4.21,5.95,4.39,4.55,4.27,4.955,4.65,3.32,3.48,3.828571429,4.69,4.68,3.76,3.91,4,4.41,4.19,4.733333333,4.32,2.83,3.41,4.42,3.47,3.84,4.39)
x.number <- c(69,62,8,80,13,12,2,22,19,49,840,44,31,56,33,58,91,8,15,86,11,69,12,24,32,27,1,4,26,4,28,33,1516,41,20,58,44,29,58,14,3,3,6,3,26,52,26,29,92,30,18,11,27,19,38,78,57,52,17,45,56,7,37,7,14,13,164,76,82,14,273,122,662,434,126,374,1017,522,374,602,164,5,191,243,134,70,23,130,306,516,414,236,172,164,92,53,50,17,22,27,92,48,30,55,28,296,35,12,350,17,22,53,97,62,92,272,242,170,37,220,452,270,392,314,150,232)
range(x.number)
#> [1]    1 1516

require(bbmle)
#> Loading required package: bbmle
#> Loading required package: stats4

# linear
a = 5; b = -0.01; sigma = 1
linreg <- function(a, b, sigma){
  y.pred <- a + b * x.number
  ll <-   -sum(dnorm(y.size, mean = y.pred, sd = sigma, log=TRUE ))
  # cat(a, b, sigma, ll, "\n") # use this to track convergence
  ll
}

mle2.linreg.model <- mle(linreg, start = list(a = 5, b = -0.01 , sigma = 1))
#> Warning in dnorm(y.size, mean = y.pred, sd = sigma, log = TRUE): NaNs produced

#> Warning in dnorm(y.size, mean = y.pred, sd = sigma, log = TRUE): NaNs produced

summary(mle2.linreg.model)
#> Maximum likelihood estimation
#> 
#> Call:
#> mle(minuslogl = linreg, start = list(a = 5, b = -0.01, sigma = 1))
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>           Estimate   Std. Error
#> a      4.702090332 0.1400488859
#> b     -0.001529292 0.0005658488
#> sigma  1.339407093 0.0843745782
#> 
#> -2 log L: 431.2136
-logLik(mle2.linreg.model)
#> 'log Lik.' 215.6068 (df=3)
AIC(mle2.linreg.model)
#> [1] 437.2136

a <- mle2.linreg.model@coef["a"]
b <- mle2.linreg.model@coef["b"]
sigma <- mle2.linreg.model@coef["sigma"]
y.pred <- a + b * x.number

plot(x.number, y.size)
lines(x.number, y.pred, col = "red")
```

[image]

```r
# skew function
aa = 4/10^27; bb = 1/10; Tmin = 2; Tmax = 300; ymin = 2; sigma = 0.1
skewfun <- function(aa, bb, Tmin, Tmax, ymin, sigma){
  y.pred <- aa * x.number * pmax(0, x.number - Tmin) * pmax(0, Tmax - x.number) ^ (1/bb) + ymin
  ll <- -sum(dnorm(y.size, mean = y.pred, sd = sigma, log=TRUE ))
  # cat(aa, bb, Tmin, Tmax, sigma, ll, "\n") # use this to track convergence
  ll
}

mle2.skewfun.model <- mle(skewfun, start = list(aa = 4/10^27, bb = 1/10 , Tmin = 2 , Tmax = 300, ymin = 2, sigma = 0.1))
#> Warning in dnorm(y.size, mean = y.pred, sd = sigma, log = TRUE): NaNs produced

#> Warning in dnorm(y.size, mean = y.pred, sd = sigma, log = TRUE): NaNs produced

#> Warning in dnorm(y.size, mean = y.pred, sd = sigma, log = TRUE): NaNs produced

#> Warning in dnorm(y.size, mean = y.pred, sd = sigma, log = TRUE): NaNs produced

summary(mle2.skewfun.model)
#> Warning in sqrt(diag(object@vcov)): NaNs produced
#> Maximum likelihood estimation
#> 
#> Call:
#> mle(minuslogl = skewfun, start = list(aa = 4/10^27, bb = 1/10, 
#>     Tmin = 2, Tmax = 300, ymin = 2, sigma = 0.1))
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>            Estimate   Std. Error
#> aa    -3.715992e-05 1.739826e-03
#> bb     2.645274e+00 1.322961e+02
#> Tmin   1.266428e+02          NaN
#> Tmax   1.396117e+02 3.574602e+02
#> ymin   4.504795e+00 1.235931e-01
#> sigma  1.377656e+00 8.678290e-02
#> 
#> -2 log L: 438.3107
-logLik(mle2.skewfun.model)
#> 'log Lik.' 219.1554 (df=6)
AIC(mle2.skewfun.model)
#> [1] 450.3107

aa <- mle2.skewfun.model@coef["aa"]
bb <- mle2.skewfun.model@coef["bb"]
Tmin <- mle2.skewfun.model@coef["Tmin"]
Tmax <- mle2.skewfun.model@coef["Tmax"]
ymin <- mle2.skewfun.model@coef["ymin"]
sigma <- mle2.skewfun.model@coef["sigma"]
y.pred <- abs(aa) * x.number * pmax(0, x.number - Tmin) * pmax(0, Tmax - x.number) ^ (1/bb) + ymin

plot(x.number, y.size)
lines(x.number, y.pred, col = "red")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-11-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I tried the method you suggested with better estimates and I'm still running into a similar error with the MLE function with the new estimates. See edit to my code above

Comment: By the way, the way I have done it with setting the param values outside the function and having cat() inside the function makes it much easier to debug.

Comment: And, your data is pretty messy, I don't expect you will get a very pretty fit.